# Proving that $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}) = 1$ if and only if $\mathbf{A}$ is the product of a non-zero column vector and a non-zero row vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, equivalence-relations, matrix-rank

$\newcommand{\mn}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\rk}[1]{\operatorname{rank}(#1)}$
$\newcommand{\t}{\mathrm{T}}$

As a beginner in linear algebra, I encountered an interesting problem
in my textbook.  I would like to have my solution verified.

## Problem

For a matrix $\mathbf{A}$, prove that
$$\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}) = 1$$
if and only if
$$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^{\mathrm{T}}$$
for some non-zero column vector
$\mathbf{a}$ and non-zero row vector $\mathbf{b}^{\mathrm{T}}$.

## My proof

Let:

- $m \times n$ be the dimensions of $\mn A$;
- $\mn F$ be the $m \times n$ canonical matrix with rank $1$;
- $\vn i_k$ be the $k$-dimensional unit vector
  $(1, 0, \dotsc, 0)^\t$.

Hence, $\mn F = \vn i_m \vn i_n^\t$.

### The *only if* direction

It is known that $\rk{\mn A} = 1$.
Therefore, there exists invertible matrices $\mn P_{(m \times m)}$ and $\mn Q_{(n \times n)}$, such that
$$ \mn P \mn A \mn Q = \mn F. $$
Thus,
$$ \mn A = \mn P^{-1} \mn F \mn Q^{-1} = \mn P^{-1} \vn i_m \vn i_n^\t \mn Q^{-1}.$$
Let $\vn a = \mn P^{-1} \vn i_m$ and $\vn b^\t = \vn i_n^\t \mn Q^{-1}$, so that $\mn A = \vn a \vn b^\t$.

Because $\det \mn P^{-1} \neq 0$, no column of $\mn P^{-1}$ consists exclusively of zeros.
$\vn a$ is just the first column of $\mn P^{-1}$, so $\vn a \neq \vn 0$.
Similarly, $\vn b^\t \neq \vn 0$.
Therefore, $\mn A = \vn a \vn b^\t$ for non-zero vectors $\vn a$ and $\vn b^\t$.
$\blacksquare$

### The *if* direction

It is known that $\mn A = \mn a \mn b^\t$ for non-zero vectors $\mn a$ and $\mn b$.
Let $a_i$ be one non-zero element of $\vn a$.
By swapping $a_1$ and $a_i$ (possibly $i = 1$), we transform $\vn a$ into $\vn a'$.
Then, build the block matrix
$$
\mn C = \begin{bmatrix}
\vn a' & \begin{matrix} \vn 0 \\ \mn I_{m-1} \end{matrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and swap its first row with its $i$th row to obtain $\mn D$,
so that the first column of $\mn D$ is equal to $\vn a$.
Hence,
$$ \det \mn D = \pm \det \mn C = \pm a_i \neq 0. $$
Let $\mn P = \mn D^{-1}$,
so
$$ \vn a = \mn D \vn i_m = \mn P^{-1} \vn i_m. $$
By the same process,
we find an invertible matrix $\mn Q$ such that
$$ \vn b^\t = \vn i_n^\t \mn Q^{-1}. $$
Therefore,
$$ \mn A = \vn a \vn b^\t
= \mn P^{-1} \vn i_m \vn i_n^\t \mn Q^{-1}
= \mn P^{-1} \mn F \mn Q^{-1}, $$
so
$$ \mn P \mn A \mn Q = \mn F, $$
which shows that $\rk{\mn A} = 1$.
$\blacksquare$

## Concerns

- Is my proof correct?  Did I misuse any theorem?
- Is my proof clear and concise?  Does any step warrant further
  explanation?  Can the notation be improved?
- Are there simpler beginner-accessible solutions?
- What else can be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Alternative proof :*

Denote by $L_1, ..., L_n$ the rows of $A$.

Then $\mathrm{rank}(A)=1$ means that all the rows are proportional to a a nonzero one, i.e. that there exists $i \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace$ such that for every $k \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace$, there exists $\alpha_k$ such that $L_k=\alpha_k L_i$.

Now let $a=L_i$ and $b=(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$ and you are done.

Comment: Remark: Any row $i$ for which $L_i\neq 0$ will do. There is at least one such $i$ since else $A$ is the zero matrix and of rank $0$.

Comment: 

Comment: I just realized that the *if* direction is intended to be a trivial application of the property that $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}) = \min\{\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}), \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B})\}$, which is proved earlier in the textbook, making an elegant proof when combined with this proof for the *only if* direction.

Comment: @L.F. You are right, this would work (but you would also have to show that the rank of $AB$ cannot be zero then !). Actually, I did not write all the details, but the point of view given in my answer can also prove the *if* direction : indeed, just write $a$ and $b$ in extenso, make the product, and you can see that all the rows of $A$ are proportional (and that one of them is nonzero), which concludes the proof. But as you say, there are probably numerous ways of solving that problem, so it is great if you have different points of view.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you focus more on the definitions than trying to compute and work with factorizations.

For example, in the if direction, suppose that $A=ab^T$ and let $v$ be any vector.  Then $Av=a(b^Tv)$.  Since $b^Tv$ is just a scalar, we find that $Av$ is a scalar multiple of $a$.  Hence, $Av\in\operatorname{Span}(a)$.  From the definition, this implies that the rank of $A$ is at most one.

Now, if you let $v=b$, then $b^Tb=\|b\|$, which is nonzero if and only if $b$ is nonzero.  Therefore, the image of $A$ is not only the zero vector, i.e., has dimension at least one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll definitely attach importance to definitions in the future.  I haven't learned vector spaces yet, as my textbook uses the determinantal definition of ranks.  I'll definitely reconsider this problem after I reach that part.

Comment: Indeed, after learning more about linear algebra, I see that my original solution is very long-winded and inelegant.  A question: can you elaborate on "Hence, $Av \in \operatorname{Span}(v)$"?  I can see that $Av \in \operatorname{Span}(a)$, but I'm unsure how you proceeded from there.

Comment: It looks like you've found a typo.  I fixed it - thanks!